# Multiple buttons to input into its own text box on same page,

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function moveNumbers(num) { 
var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
txt=txt + num; 
document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
} 
</script>
Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="text" id="result" size="20">

<br>
<br>
<br>

<script> function moveNumbers(num) { 
var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
txt=txt + num; 
document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
} 
</script>
Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="a" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="b" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="c" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)"> <input type="text" id="result" size="20">

</html>
</body>
```

Hi all, I have 2 button sets, "1, 2, 3" and "a, b, c". Having trouble trying separate the inputs to there own text boxes on the same page any ideas?. Tried a few things here and there like changing "value" "name" etc. Fairly new at this. Thanks for your help....

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID. `id = "result"` this needs to be unique for every element. What are you trying to achieve that each time a button set is clicked i.e abc that the corresponding textbox has the lastes value (last clicked)?

Comment: Yep to the above reply. Buttons 1, 2, 3, input the text from the button name into the text box that is next to it. So say click button 1 -> text would say "1". Click button "2" and replace text "1" with the number "2" etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do these things

1) Never have same ID's on the same page they should be different.

> This attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique
>   in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element when
>   linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with
>   CSS)

more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Global_attributes).

2) Never have same name for two functions.

3) Your `<body>` tag should be closed before `<html>` tag.

```
 <html>
    <body>
    Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers1(this.value)">  
    <input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers1(this.value)">  
    <input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers1(this.value)">  
    <input type="text" id="result" size="20">

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <script> 
    function moveNumbers2(num) { 
       var txt=document.getElementById("result2").value; 
       txt=txt + num; 
       document.getElementById("result2").value=txt; 
    } 
    function moveNumbers1(num) { 
       var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
       txt=txt + num; 
       document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
    } 
    </script>
    Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="a" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers2(this.value)">  
    <input type="button" value="b" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers2(this.value)">  
    <input type="button" value="c" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers2(this.value)"> <input type="text" id="result2" size="20">

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help all, JJPA has solved my problem I now see what the problem was. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Dont use same id's in same page for component and function name as well.

The second function will be overwritten on first function (Which means first function will be discarded, it will work).

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

function moveNumbers(num) { 
var txt=document.getElementById("result1").value; 
txt=txt + num; 
document.getElementById("result1").value=txt; 
} 

function moveAlpha(num) { 
var txt=document.getElementById("result").value; 
txt=txt + num; 
document.getElementById("result").value=txt; 
} 

</script>
Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">  
<input type="text" id="result1" size="20">
<br>
<br>
<br>
Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="a" name="no" onclick="moveAlpha(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="b" name="no" onclick="moveAlpha(this.value)">  
<input type="button" value="c" name="no" onclick="moveAlpha(this.value)"> <input type="text" id="result" size="20">

</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

JJPA has highlighted the problems you have with your HTML and javascript the only thing i'd add is that you can create one function to do both jobs by making them reusable. This is more efficient and reduces the amount of code you need.

Something like this

```
moveNumbers(num, element){
  var txt=document.getElementById(element).value; 
  txt=txt + num;
  document.getElementById(element).value=txt; 
}
```

and then you call the function like this

```
Select numbers: <br> <input type="button" value="1" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers1(this.value, "result")">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers1(this.value, "result")">
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers1(this.value, "result")">  
<input type="text" id="result" size="20">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use spacs inbetween ur tags like this:

```
<input type="button" value="a" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp; </input>
<input type="button" value="b" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp; </input>
<input type="button" value="c" name="no" onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">
```

Also u can have more buttons, once if any one is clicked its value get posted.